# What happened to Valyria?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I've read the books and all but what happened to Valyria?
Are there any outside sources?
If you think about it, the whole empire was destroyed in this apocalyptic event. The event had to be so bad that a few hundred years afterwards no one would go there.
If it was a volcano it would be pretty unlikely that they'd still shun that place in my opinion. Same with an earthquake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this was not just a single earthquake or volcano. Consider [this summary](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Doom_of_Valyria):

> The cataclysm hit the Valyrian capital city Valyria, fragmenting the land surrounding the city into numerous smaller islands, creating the Smoking Sea between them. the Freehold was annihilated in a single night of fire and storm, with great earthquakes and volcanic eruptions laying waste to the empire. The area is now described as "demon-haunted." Most people are afraid to go there, saying, *"The Doom still rules in Valyria."*

Here is a map of the fragmented peninsula, to illustrate the magnitude of what happened. The entire land mass was separated, and Smoking Sea still smolders and is unsafe for travel:

[image]

Comment: wow, so this volcano was for more than a hundred years active without rest... wow... but thanks

Comment: @Armin: IRRC, there were at least 14 volcanoes that erupted more or less at the same time.
"Fourteen or fourteen thousand. What man dares count them? It is not wise for mortals to look too deeply at those fires, my friend. Those are the fires of god’s own wrath, and no human flame can match them. We are small creatures, men."
And it is said the fires were so hot, they even killed the dragons that were in Valyria at that time.

Comment: @StefanUrziceanu do you have a source where i can look that up?

Comment: @Armin http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fourteen_Flames

Comment: I can't give an answer, since the question is marked as a duplicate, but read the second post on this forum page:
http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/topic/49269-the-doom-of-valyria/page-4